# PHP/mysql: Use column value in dropdown menu, actually add PK ID value in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu, primary-key

I'm learning PHP/mysql and making a database for schoolwork. I had to remake my tables with ID numbers as the PK, which kind of set me back. I have drop down menus in my add record forms where relationships are applied, which generate from the other tables. They worked fine before, but now because my foreign keys have to be numbers, it doesn't recognise the text in the drop down.

Are there ways that I can use a specific value as a drop down option in the form, and in my INSERT query actually add the ID number in it's place? Say if I had "John Smith" with a WriterID of 12, could my code could add in the 12 but the user would see the name? I've been wracking my brain over this since early this morning.

Here is the insert code both the necessary parts of my form and the query itself (on separate pages in my code). At the time I copied this I was playing around with the idea of GET instead of POST for the last two options. I also tried some seperate SELECT queries in the second part, so feel free to tell me if anything is unnecessary. Thanks in advance.

FORM

```
            $con = mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
            mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

            $result = @mysql_query("select WriterID, WriterName from dbase.writer2");
            print("Writer: ");
            print("<select name=\"WriterName\">\n");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $WriterName = $row['WriterName'];
                print("<option value = " . $row['WriterID'] . ">$WriterName\n");

            }

            print("</select>\n");
            print("<a href=\"insert_writer.php\">If Writer not in list, add here</a>\n");
            print("<br>\n");

        $result = @mysql_query("select PublisherID, PublisherTitle from dbase.publisher2");
            print("Publisher: ");
            print("<select name=\"PublisherTitle\">\n");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
                $PublisherTitle = $row['PublisherTitle'];
                print("<option value = " . $row['PublisherID'] . ">$PublisherTitle<br\n");

            }
            print("</select>\n");
            print("<a href=\"insert_publisher.php\">If Publisher not in list, add here</a><br>\n");
            mysql_close($con);

        <input type="Submit" value="Submit">

   </form>

 print("<a href=\"demo13.php\">Back to Main</a><br>\n");
 print("<a href=\"add.php\">Add Records Page</a><br>\n")
```

QUERY

```
        //retreiving the form text fields and assigning a variable to them
        $SeriesName=$_POST['SeriesName'];
        $SeriesGenre=$_POST['SeriesGenre'];
        $NumberOfVolumes=$_POST['NumberOfVolumes'];
        $MainWriter=$_GET['WriterID'];
        $SeriesPublisher=$_GET['PublisherID'];

        //using the aformentioned variables for the credentials in order to access the database
        $con = mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);
        mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

        $query = "SELECT writer2.WriterID FROM writer2
                  WHERE series2.MainWriter = writer2.WriterID";

        $MainWriter = mysql_query($query);



        $query = "SELECT publisher2.PublisherID FROM publisher2
                  WHERE series2.SeriesPublisher = publisher2.PublisherID";

        mysql_query($query);

        $SeriesPublisher = mysql_query($query);

        //Using SQL code to insert the information into the database.
        $query = "INSERT INTO series2 (SeriesName,SeriesGenre,NumberOfVolumes,MainWriter,SeriesPublisher)
                  VALUES('$SeriesName','$SeriesGenre','$NumberOfVolumes','$MainWriter','$SeriesPublisher')";

        //running the SQL code and closing the database connection.
      mysql_query($query);

      if (mysql_affected_rows($con) == -1)
      {
          print("An error has occured. Record insert failed " . mysql_error() . "<br\n");
      }
      else
      {
          print("<b>Record entered successfully</b><br>\n");
          print("$SeriesName<br>\n" .
                "$SeriesGenre<br>\n" .
                "$NumberOfVolumes<br>\n" .
                "$WriterName<br<\n" .
                "$PublisherTitle");
   print("ID for this record: " . mysql_insert_id() ."<br>\n");
      }       
      mysql_close($con);

      print("<a href=\"demo13.php\">Back to Main</a><br>\n");
      print("<a href=\"insert_series.php\">Add Another Series</a><br>\n");
      print("<a href=\"add.php\">Add Records Page</a><br>\n")
```

Comment: When you say you want the user to see the name, on which page do you mean?  The form or the query?

Comment: Also note that you should change this line: `print("<option value = " . $row['PublisherID'] . ">$PublisherTitle<br\n")` to this `print("<option value=\"" . $row['PublisherID'] . "\">$PublisherTitle<br />\n")`

Answer (score 2):

Your option blocks need to contain the value in quotes, no spaces.

i.e. `<option value="1">John Smith</option>`

Your current code would produce `<option value = 1>John Smith</option>` which is invalid markup.

You may have other issues, but your code is a bit linguini.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing this:

```
$MainWriter=$_GET['WriterID'];
```

But your select tag is:

```
<select name="WriterName">
```

Which causes $_GET['WriterName'] to be created.  You should rename the select to "WriterID".

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to this line of the code:

```
 print("<option value = " . $row['PublisherID'] . ">$PublisherTitle<br\n");
```

which is horribly broken, lets try this instead:

```
echo "<option value='". $row['PublisherID']."'>".$PublisherTitle."</option>";
```

There is no need for a `<br />` after it (especially since you did not close it, it is not an element that needs that kind of return after it.  This will pass the PublisherID to the form action as $_REQUEST['PublisherTitle'], this should be the same for your WriterName one also.  You are also missing tons of ending tags & such, just an FYI..

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help everyone, with the code as well as pointing out the various errors. And also for pointing out my layout issues in a non-mocking manner (I'm teaching myself).

I changed my select code using some of the suggestions here, and adjusted my output on the other side with the $_REQUEST, and it worked fine. Here are the key changes I made the to the code for posterity.

```
print("Publisher: ");
print("<select name=\"PublisherTitle\">\n");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $PublisherTitle = $row['PublisherTitle'];
    print("<option value=\"" . $row['PublisherID'] . "\">$PublisherTitle<br />\n");
```

(Ditto with my writer select)

And on the query page

```
$MainWriter=$_REQUEST['WriterName'];
$SeriesPublisher=$_REQUEST['PublisherTitle'];
```